# How to set ComboBox.SelectionBoxItemTemplate in Silverlight 3.0

Tags: silverlight, xaml, list, combobox

I need to be able to have a SelectionBoxItemTemplate for my ComboBox, but am unsure how to do this or if there is another way in Silverlight 3.0 to do this.
In my drop-down list I have a List of CheckBoxes, and TextBlocks, this works fine,
however the Selected Item is one of these when I click on it, i.e. the Checkbox shows in the top of the Combobox, I don't want this, instead I want it to say "Display", as this is a list of display settings, how can the ComboBox be changed to allow this in Silverlight?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on what you want?  A picture says a thousand words....

Comment: Yes I will edit, I need the selected item of the ComboBox to be different from the main list, this would not be a problem with a ListBox, but the ListItems like the CheckBox appear in the SelectedItem, I don't want this.

Comment: I am still not sure what you want to achieve, but I will throw in my two cents as well.  Could you not just build the part you want to display on the SelectionChanged event, and do something like 

    ((CoboBoxItem)yourcombobox.SelectedItem).Content = "Whatever you want here";

However, even if this works, the content of that Item will still be set once you unselected it.

Comment: I don't think changing just the SelectedItem worked as this shares the same implied Item Template as the rest of the items, which are CheckBoxes and TextBlocks, I want it to be just a TextBlock with the whatever I want in it, I wonder if I have to modify the Control Template but am unsure what to do with it to get the behaviour I want from the ComboBox.
I have re-worded my question to state the behaviour I want, It can be done in WPF as I have seen it, but cannot seem to find a way in Silverlight which works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not actually possible in Silverlight 3, although the Property can be read, it cannot be sent, marking this as answer, but hope Silverlight 4.0 will support this.